# Mysql Many to Many table creation error: ERROR 1005 table exists

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship

I am trying to make a many to many relationship using a connecting table
but the error:"ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'mysql_vb_net_hospital_schema.#sql-8f8_3' (errno: 121)" comes up

the two tables are patient_table, illness_table. the connector table is m2m_illness_patient

description of illness_table:[image]

description of patient_table:[image]
description of m2m_illness_patient:[image]

I add 2 foreign keys in m2m_illness_patient and reference them

referencing to illness table
[image]
referencing to patient table
[image]

But error comes as follows:
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'mysql_vb_net_hospital_schema.#sql-8f8_3' (errno: 121)

SQL Statement:

ALTER TABLE `mysql_vb_net_hospital_schema`.`m2m_illness_patient`

ADD CONSTRAINT `Illness_Id`

FOREIGN KEY (`Illness_Id`)

REFERENCES `mysql_vb_net_hospital_schema`.`illness_table` (`Illness_Id`)

ON DELETE CASCADE

ON UPDATE CASCADE,

ADD CONSTRAINT `Patient_Id`

FOREIGN KEY (`Patient_Id`)

REFERENCES `mysql_vb_net_hospital_schema`.`patient_table` (`Patient_Id`)

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'm2m_illness_patient' already exists

SQL Statement:

CREATE TABLE `m2m_illness_patient` (

`Illness_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,

`Patient_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`Illness_Id`,`Patient_Id`),

KEY `Patient_Id_idx` (`Patient_Id`,`Illness_Id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

How can I create this many to many relationship without this error?

Comment: ok so when I set illness table alone it makes relationship successfully. but when I try to connect patient after that the error comes. so problem in with patient table

Comment: Could you try to build your tables through command line? Create a test database, then do `use test`, `create table illness_table (illness_id int primary key);`, `create table patient_table (patient_id int priamary key);`, `create table m2m_illness_patient (illness_id int, patient_id int, primary key (illness_id, patient_id));` and then your alter statement (don't include schema name). All works on 5.6.14 MySQL Community Server. (OSX 10.9.4)